# Create space AFTER each section in Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, text-formatting, layout

I want to leave some blank space at the end of each subsection of a document.

```
 +---------------- Page 1/2 -+     +---------------- Page 2/2 -+
 | 1. SECTION                |     | text text text            |
 | 1.1. SUBSECTION           |     |                           |
 | text text text text text  |     |                           |
 | text text text text text  |     |                           |
 |                           |     |                           |
 | text text text text text  |     | 1.3. SUBSECTION           |
 | text text text text text  |     | text text text text text  |
 |                           |     | text text text            |
 |                           |     |                           |
 |                           |     | text                      |
 |                           |     |                           |
 | 1.2. SUBSECTION           |     |                           |
 | text text text text text  |     |                           |
 | text text text text text  |     |                           |
 +---------------------------+     +---------------------------+
```

I.e. is it possible to say:

> Insert a 2cm distance before each heading of style `Heading 2`, but not if **(a)** the previous paragraph is any heading style or **(b)** the paragraph is at the start of the page.

### What I tried

**Alignment > Intends & Spacing > Spacing Above Paragraph.** Using this setting creates the wanted space between subsections. However, it will *also* add the same space right after *1. SECTION* or at the top of a page. Both are unwanted.

**Create a separate "Heading 2 Nospace" Style.** When creating a separate "nospace" heading style, that is used at the beginning of a *SECTION*, the layout looks mostly as wanted. However, **(a)** it doesn't solve unwanted space at the beginning of a page, when a *SUBSECTION* starts at the top of the page by chance and **(b)** it makes setting up Chapter numbers complicated, because they have to be set up separately and consistently for both *Heading 2* and *Heading 2 Nospace* styles. I'm not sure it is even possible to get this entirely right.

**Manually adding a "spacing" paragraph after each section.** Define a layout type "spacing", and set it as "next style" for each relevant heading and itself. Creating a complete paragraph then consists of **(a)** selecting the heading style **(b)** pressing Enter twice **(c)** edit the first paragraph of the section and make it a *Text Body* section. This is better than adding newlines manually, but still awkward. Also, it can still go wrong if it ends up as the first paragraph on a page.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party but here's how I achieved it.

Click anywhere in section, then right click and choose "Edit Section".

[image: choose edit section after you right click on section]

Click "Options" in the following dialog.

[image: click options]

Adjust the spacing in the next dialog.

[image: adjust spacing]

Comment: What you describe applies to column spacing. The question is about spacing between text sections, i.e. before a heading, but not at the start of a page. To be fair, I wasn't aware that LibreOffice Writer uses the "section" terminology also in this different sense.